# Calculating the angle to move at

Tags: java, game-physics

I was wondering how I would calculate the direction in which an object will travel to a given point. So if I had a ball at the coordinates 10,10 and I gave it a coordinates 15,15 it would know to move up and to the right by same distance (i.e java y coordinates increase upwards and travels the same distance towards right until it got there). But if I gave the same ball the 20,15 it would not move in both axis evenly (ie the distance up and then to the right). It would be great if I could have the output in `int` values. Like the number of pixels to move upwards per tick and the number of pixels to move across per tick. (Obviously, that would have a cap so it is really just regulating one of the variables to get the desired course).

Thanks heaps.

Comment: Check [Line Generation Algorithm](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_graphics/line_generation_algorithm.htm).

Comment: I think you should also show your code that you are attempting to write and the specific problems that you are facing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about elementary mathematics rather than programming

Comment: Java y coordinates actually increase downwards. DROY edited the post and changed it to the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [atan2()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2%28double,%20double%29) method returns the angle you need to move. For example:

```
double angle = Math.atan(end.y - start.y, end.x - start.x);
```

As in all Java trig functions, `angle` will be in radians.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using [Apache Commons Math library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/geometry/euclidean/twod/Vector2D.html)